# Return max value of each partition

Tags: postgresql

I have this table:

```
create table some_date
(
    dt date,
    t time without time zone,
    price numeric   
)
```

This is a sample data set:

```
insert into some_date 
values ('2021-11-17','06:39:37.7663',2),
('2021-11-17','06:39:38.7663',5),
('2021-11-17','06:39:39.7663',0),
('2021-11-17','06:39:40.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:39:41.7663',3),
('2021-11-17','06:39:42.7663',7),
('2021-11-17','06:39:43.7663',5),
('2021-11-17','06:39:44.7663',6),
('2021-11-17','06:39:45.7663',3),
('2021-11-17','06:39:46.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:39:47.7663',2),
('2021-11-17','06:39:48.7663',5),
('2021-11-17','06:39:49.7663',8),
('2021-11-17','06:39:50.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:39:51.7663',4),
('2021-11-17','06:39:52.7663',5),
('2021-11-17','06:39:53.7663',6),
('2021-11-17','06:39:54.7663',6),
('2021-11-17','06:39:55.7663',7),
('2021-11-17','06:39:56.7663',8),
('2021-11-17','06:39:57.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:39:58.7663',7),
('2021-11-17','06:39:59.7663',8),
('2021-11-17','06:40:00.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:01.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:00.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:01.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:02.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:03.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:04.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:05.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:06.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:07.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:08.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:09.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:10.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:11.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:12.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:13.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:14.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:15.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:16.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:17.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:18.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:19.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:20.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:21.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:22.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:23.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:24.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:25.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:26.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:27.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:28.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:29.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:30.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:31.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:32.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:33.7663',1),
('2021-11-17','06:40:34.7663',9),
('2021-11-17','06:40:35.7663',1);
```

I want to query data per min like max, min ..., so I use `row_number()` and partition to set group by a minute

```
with t as (
    select * , extract(hour from t) as h,  extract(minute from t) as m
    from  price
), tt as (
select * , row_number() over(partition by h,m order by t) as t_sequence
from t)
```

and now I want to query by this 'partition', how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that what you want to use is "grouping"instead of "partitioning":

```sql
with t as (
    select * , extract(hour from t) as h,  extract(minute from t) as m
    from  price
), tt as (
select * , row_number() over(partition by h,m order by t) as t_sequence
from t)
```

Or the query without the CTE:

```sql
SELECT
  extract(hour from t) as h,
  extract(minute from t) as m, 
  max(price) AS max_price, 
  min(price) AS min_price
FROM some_table
GROUP BY h, m;
```

Comment: but if i want to select the first and the last entry in every min how do I do that?